# Applying OOTB styles to extended component

Tags: styling, spartacus-storefront

I have to extend the OrderOverviewComponent, but when I create a new component that extends the component, the styling is no longer applied because Spartacus is not styling on class name but on 'placeholder class'

I looked at the css-architecture documentation, but the examples like this is not working.

```
cx-link {
  @extend %cx-link !optional;
  a {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

How I can `@extend` my new component, and apply OOTB styling?

```
lib-xxx-order-review {
  background-color: red;

  @extend %cx-order-overview !optional;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this might not work is because you need to have the import of the Spartacus file you are extending in your custom style file.

You have two options for extending the Spartacus styles:

1. Extending the OOTB style in your `styles.scss` and defining your custom styles in the component style

```
// styles.scss
$styleVersion: 3.4;
@import "~@spartacus/styles/index";

app-custom-product-intro {
  @extend %cx-product-intro !optional;
}
```

```
// custom-product-intro.component.ts
:host {
  .code {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

The following example will use the OOTB style and override the `.code` color.

2. Extend the style in your component scss

```
// custom-product-intro.component.ts

// Import required by the OOTB file
@import "~@spartacus/styles/scss/cxbase/mixins";
// Import the OOTB component style before importing it
@import "~@spartacus/styles/scss/components/product/details/product-intro";

:host {
  .code {
    color: yellow;
  }
  @extend %cx-product-intro !optional;
}
```

We will update the documentation to add above details.

Comment: Thanks L Tiger! My solution is ```@import "~@spartacus/styles/scss/mixins";
@import "~@spartacus/styles/scss/components/misc/order-overview/order-overview";

:host {
  @extend %cx-order-overview !optional;
}```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are importing styles with `@import`.

`@use` do not work for extending OOTB component placeholder